# Let $H$ be a subset of $\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $H$ contains polynomials in which the powers of $x$ are even. Show that $H$ is a subring of $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $H$ be a subset of $\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $H$ contains polynomials in which the powers of $x$ are even. Show that $H$ is a subring of $\Bbb Z[x]$. Is $H$ an ideal?

Let $f,g \in \Bbb Z[x]$. Then $f=a_{2k}x^{2k} + a_{2(k-1)}x^{2(k-1)} + \dots +a_0$ and $g=b_{2t}x^{2t} + b_{2(t-1)}x^{2(t-1)} + \dots +b_0$  for $k,t \in \Bbb Z$.

Now $f-g$ is certainly a polynoimal with even degree powers of $x$ since I can group the terms w.r.t to the $x$ power terms. Likewise with the product $fg$ we're only adding even numbers with even numbers regarding the powers of $x$ and since even $+$ even $=$ even. So $f-g \in H$ and $fg \in H$.

$H$ is not an ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$ as then we would have that for any $r \in \Bbb Z[x]$ and $f \in H$ the product $rf \in H$. But let $r = x^3$ and $H = x^2$. Now $rh = x^5 \notin H$.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is ill-phrased. The set
$$
H=\{x^2\}
$$
(just one element in it)surely contains polynomials consisting of monomials of even degree and it's obviously neither an ideal nor a subring.

If you consider the set $H$ of **all** such polynomials, it is still not an ideal simply because $1\in H$ and $H\neq\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It is a subring, though, because it's the image of the ring homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}[t]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[x]\qquad
t\mapsto x^2.
$$